# Is it redundant to check if a value is unique in both the application and database?

Tags: php, mysql

So let's say a user registers for an account, I would like to check if the email being used is already associated with another account...

On the database side, I put a unique constraint on the email column. Now on the application side, should I run a query to check whether that email is already in use and then if it isn't, run another query to insert the user? Or should I ignore that step and since I already have a unique constraint in the database column, I should just attempt to insert the user and if I get an error, I know the email is already in use?

Is running a query just to check for the email being redundant or is it a necessary step and why?

I am using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: My preference would be to go ahead and insert the record based on the unique constraint.

Comment: It is redundant as you get exactly the same information from comprehending the error message

Comment: Its better to check and revert user with a prompt if its already exists else just create it.

Comment: I prefer to use AJAX once the user has taken focus off the email field to check whether it's unique. If it's not, an error can prompt them to re-do it before submitting the form. It's **much** more user friendly.

Comment: I'd say for data-integrity you'll want the unique constraint in the database, for usability you'll want the extra check before (you could e.g. run the check asynchronously and tell the user before he finishes the - possibly large - complete registration form).

Comment: @kingkero Is it not good if user get to know that he is recreating account? else he never get to know if account got created now or it was already there.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Either way, the user will get an error message, this is just asking how I should go about things in the back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's redundant, but you might want to do it.

You have two choices, really:

1. Check in app, then add to database.  There is a race condition there, so you need to Wrap the check-set in an application level mutex, or
2. Just push into the database and catch any exception raised from the database layer and handle (taking care to distinguish between constraint violation on column exceptions from all other kinds of possible run time exceptions).

Depending upon the relative ease of these two approaches, decide which works for you.

Comment: I'm not sure how the first approach works, but I was initially leaning towards the second so I think I will go with that.